# Use contour Integration to establish $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}{\rm d}x=\frac\pi{ab(a+b)}$ for $a,b>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Can someone help me figure this out please? This is the question along with what I have so far.

> Use contour integration to establish 
>   $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}{\rm d}x=\frac\pi{ab(a+b)},~~~\text{where}~a,b>0$$

Assume $R>1$. Then, the improper integral can be written as
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{_R}^R\frac1{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}{\rm d}x$$
Let $\gamma$ be the positively oriented contour consisting of $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2$, where $\gamma_1=\{z=x+iy\in\Bbb C\mid-R\le x\le R\}$ and $\gamma_2=\{z=Re^{i\theta}\in\Bbb C\mid0\le\theta\le\pi\}$. Define the functions $f(z)=\frac1{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}$ and...

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @mrtaurho My apologies, and thank you for the help! I did not know how to use code to write the limit and integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The poles are simple, and located at $\pm ai,\pm bi$.  You could use the residue theorem, if you prove the integral on the part of the contour off the real axis goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure where to get the imaginary parts from using this!

Comment: They surely go to zero.